# Image segmentation in C# (line segmentation and character segmentation)

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, image-segmentation

i was looking for an example for segmentation based on line and characters. but i couldn't find any helpful resource. if someone can provide me an example how to do it, it would be nice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a OCR (Optical Character Recognition) library. There are several free and commercial libraries available. Checkout the wikipedia articles on "[Optical character recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)" and "[List of Optical character recognition software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_character_recognition_software)".

Comment: i need to implement this without libraries. :(

Comment: @FlaMM3R: is this a home work? You can use source that dov linked as starting point for your work